# Can I map the first element of a pair without arrows?

Tags: haskell, arrows

I'm eyeing functors, applicative functors… I'm not sure how to get where I want, but I have the feeling that following the types should get me closer.

Is there a simple way to make a `map`-alike which only applies to the first element of a 2-tuple? Taking `first` from `Control.Arrow` and using `Arrow (->)`, this does the trick nicely:

```
map . first :: (b -> c) -> [(b, d)] -> [(c, d)]
```

My only concern is that I have yet to gain a real intuition for arrows, and so I'll probably find myself in deep water sooner or later if I keep this up. Plus, this seems to be a rather convenient case that can't be generalised.

Can I get the same functionality by using something from functors, monads or whatever else, while getting to the heart of what I want? I was toying around with

```
\f -> map (f `on` fst)
```

-like ideas, but couldn't quite get there.

Comment: If using an abstraction you don't understand makes you uncomfortable, there is *absolutely nothing* wrong with using the less abstracted version `map (\(a, b) -> (f a, b))`.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions! This has been really enlightening. Have accepted the top-voted answer by you.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413930 if you feel uncomfortable with `map . first`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Arrows have nice combinators for operating on tuples. You can almost think of them as the missing tuple functions!

So e.g.

```
> :t \f -> map (f *** id)
  :: (b -> c) -> [(b, c')] -> [(c, c')]
```

is a useful way for mapping over the first component.

Comment: You can also use (from Control.Arrow) "map (first f)" to apply a function to the first element of a pair and similarly "map (second f)" to apply it to the second element.

Answer (score 5):

Another abstraction that can do this kind of thing is a bifunctor.  Edward Kmett has a package called [bifunctors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors).  [Data.Bifunctor](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bifunctors/0.1.3.3/doc/html/Data-Bifunctor.html) has a type class for exactly this functionality and it includes in instance for 2-tuples.

Answer (score 2):

So you're looking for a function of type `(a -> b) -> (a,c) -> (b,c)`. It would be great if you could just write

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
instance Functor (,c) where
    fmap f (x,c) = (f x, c)
```

but unfortunately tuple sections only work on the value level. I don't know if there's a theoretical reason for this; I suppose it messes up higher-order type unification.

Hayoo came up with the package [Data.Tuple.HT](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/utility-ht/latest/doc/html/Data-Tuple-HT.html) where the function is called `mapFst`.

Without going up to bifunctors (the BiFunctor instance for `(,)` really does what you want and nothing more) or arrows, there's no way to get what you want, that I'm aware of at least.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that there are too many ways -- I think I would go with Daniel Wagner's advice -- but here's another for your amusement:

```
{-#LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, MultiParamTypeClasses  #-}
import Control.Newtype

newtype P a b = P {p:: (b, a)} deriving (Show,Eq,Ord,Functor)
instance Newtype (P a b) (b,a) where pack = P; unpack = p

 -- *Main> fmap even ("Hi",4)
 -- ("Hi",True)
 -- *Main> map (fmap even) [("Hi",4),("Bye",5)]
 -- [("Hi",True),("Bye",False)]
 -- *Main> under P (fmap even) (4,"Hi")
 -- (True,"Hi")
 -- *Main> map (under P (fmap even) ) [(4,"Hi"),(5,"Bye")]
 -- [(True,"Hi"),(False,"Bye")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is the [BiFunctor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors) package.

Or you could use a reversed pair type:

```
data Flip a b = Flip b a

instance Functor (Flip a) where
  fmap f (Flip x y) = Flip (f x) y
```