# Type-level nats with literals and an injective successor? (N-ary compose)

Tags: haskell, ghc, dependent-type

I'm generalizing [this `n`-ary complement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/422818/470844) to an `n`-ary compose, but I'm having trouble making the interface nice.  Namely, I can't figure out how to use numeric literals at the type level while still being able to pattern match on successors.

## Rolling my own nats

Using roll-my-own nats, I can make `n`-ary compose work, but I can only pass `n` as an iterated successor, not as a literal:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module RollMyOwnNats where

import Data.List (genericIndex)

-- import Data.Proxy
data Proxy (n::Nat) = Proxy

----------------------------------------------------------------
-- Stuff that works.

data Nat = Z | S Nat

class Compose (n::Nat) b b' t t' where
  compose :: Proxy n -> (b -> b') -> t -> t'

instance Compose Z b b' b b' where
  compose _ f x = f x

instance Compose n b b' t t' => Compose (S n) b b' (a -> t) (a -> t') where
  compose _ g f x = compose (Proxy::Proxy n) g (f x)

-- Complement a binary relation.
compBinRel :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> (a -> a -> Bool)
compBinRel = compose (Proxy::Proxy (S (S Z))) not

----------------------------------------------------------------
-- Stuff that does not work.

instance Num Nat where
  fromInteger n = iterate S Z `genericIndex` n
-- I now have 'Nat' literals:
myTwo :: Nat
myTwo = 2
-- But GHC thinks my type-level nat literal is a 'GHC.TypeLits.Nat',
-- even when I say otherwise:
compBinRel' :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> (a -> a -> Bool)
compBinRel' = compose (Proxy::Proxy (2::Nat)) not
{-
    Kind mis-match
    An enclosing kind signature specified kind `Nat',
    but `2' has kind `GHC.TypeLits.Nat'
    In an expression type signature: Proxy (2 :: Nat)
    In the first argument of `compose', namely
      `(Proxy :: Proxy (2 :: Nat))'
    In the expression: compose (Proxy :: Proxy (2 :: Nat)) not
-}
```

## Using `GHC.TypeLits.Nat`

Using `GHC.TypeLits.Nat`, I get type-level nat literals, but there is no successor constructor that I can find, and using the type function `(1 +)` doesn't work, because GHC (7.6.3) can't reason about injectivity of type functions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

module UseGHCTypeLitsNats where

import GHC.TypeLits

-- import Data.Proxy
data Proxy (t::Nat) = Proxy

----------------------------------------------------------------
-- Stuff that works.

class Compose (n::Nat) b b' t t' where
  compose :: Proxy n -> (b -> b') -> t -> t'

instance Compose 0 b b' b b' where
  compose _ f x = f x

instance (Compose n b b' t t' , sn ~ (1 + n)) => Compose sn b b' (a -> t) (a -> t') where
  compose _ g f x = compose (Proxy::Proxy n) g (f x)

----------------------------------------------------------------
-- Stuff that does not work.

-- Complement a binary relation.
compBinRel , compBinRel' :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> (a -> a -> Bool)
compBinRel = compose (Proxy::Proxy 2) not
{-
    Couldn't match type `1 + (1 + n)' with `2'
    The type variable `n' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the expression: compose (Proxy :: Proxy 2) not
    In an equation for `compBinRel':
        compBinRel = compose (Proxy :: Proxy 2) not
-}
{-
    No instance for (Compose n Bool Bool Bool Bool)
      arising from a use of `compose'
    The type variable `n' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there is a potential instance available:
      instance Compose 0 b b' b b'
-}
compBinRel' = compose (Proxy::Proxy (1+(1+0))) not
{-
    Couldn't match type `1 + (1 + 0)' with `1 + (1 + n)'
    NB: `+' is a type function, and may not be injective
    The type variable `n' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Expected type: Proxy (1 + (1 + 0))
      Actual type: Proxy (1 + (1 + n))
    In the first argument of `compose', namely
      `(Proxy :: Proxy (1 + (1 + 0)))'
-}
```

I agree that [semantic editor combinators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/415154/470844) are more elegant and more general here -- and concretely, it will always be easy enough to write `(.) . (.) . ...` (`n` times) instead of `compose (Proxy::Proxy n)` -- but I'm frustrated that I can't make the `n`-ary composition work as well as I expected.  Also, it seems I would run into similar problems for other uses of `GHC.TypeLits.Nat`, e.g. when trying to define a type function:

```
type family   T (n::Nat) :: *
type instance T 0     = ...
type instance T (S n) = ...
```

## UPDATE: Summary and adaptation of the accepted answer

There's a lot of interesting stuff going on in the accepted answer,
but the key for me is the Template Haskell trick in the GHC 7.6
solution: that effectively lets me add type-level literals to my GHC
7.6.3 version, which already had injective successors.

Using my types above, I define literals via TH:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

module RollMyOwnLiterals where

import Language.Haskell.TH

data Nat = Z | S Nat

nat :: Integer -> Q Type
nat 0 = [t| Z |]
nat n = [t| S $(nat (n-1)) |]
```

where I've moved my `Nat` declaration into the new module to avoid an
import loop.  I then modify my `RollMyOwnNats` module:

```
+import RollMyOwnLiterals
...
-data Nat = Z | S Nat
...
+compBinRel'' :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> (a -> a -> Bool)
+compBinRel'' = compose (Proxy::Proxy $(nat 2)) not
```

Comment: To answer the question hidden in the comments: `2::Nat` won't type-check because GHC only uses `fromInteger` to create value level numerals, not type level numerals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** Rewrote answer. It was getting a little bulky (and a little buggy).

### GHC 7.6

Since type level `Nat`s are somewhat... incomplete (?) in GHC 7.6, the least verbose way of achieving what you want is a combination of GADTs and type families.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeFamilies #-}

module Nats where

-- Type level nats
data Zero
data Succ n

-- Value level nats
data N n f g where
    Z :: N Zero (a -> b) a
    S :: N n f g -> N (Succ n) f (a -> g)

type family Compose n f g
type instance Compose Zero (a -> b) a = b
type instance Compose (Succ n) f (a -> g) = a -> Compose n f g

compose :: N n f g -> f -> g -> Compose n f g
compose Z f x = f x
compose (S n) f g = compose n f . g
```

The advantage of this particular implementation is that it doesn't use type classes, so applications of `compose` aren't subject to the monomorphism restriction. For example, `compBinRel = compose (S (S Z)) not` will type check without type annotations.

We can make this nicer with a little Template Haskell:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Nats.TH where

import Language.Haskell.TH

nat :: Integer -> Q Exp
nat 0 = conE 'Z
nat n = appE (conE 'S) (nat (n - 1))
```

Now we can write `compBinRel = compose $(nat 2) not`, which is much more pleasant for larger numbers. Some may consider this "cheating", but seeing as we're just implementing a little syntactic sugar, I think it's alright :)

### GHC 7.8

The following works on GHC 7.8:

```
-- A lot more extensions.
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances, GADTs, MultiParamTypeClasses, PolyKinds, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators, UndecidableInstances #-}

module Nats where

import GHC.TypeLits

data N = Z | S N

data P n = P

type family Index n where
    Index 0 = Z
    Index n = S (Index (n - 1))

-- Compose is defined using Z/S instead of 0, 1, ... in order to avoid overlapping.
class Compose n f r where
    type Return n f r
    type Replace n f r
    compose' :: P n -> (Return n f r -> r) -> f -> Replace n f r

instance Compose Z a b where
    type Return Z a b = a
    type Replace Z a b = b
    compose' _ f x = f x

instance Compose n f r => Compose (S n) (a -> f) r where
    type Return (S n) (a -> f) r = Return n f r
    type Replace (S n) (a -> f) r = a -> Replace n f r
    compose' x f g = compose' (prev x) f . g
      where
        prev :: P (S n) -> P n
        prev P = P

compose :: Compose (Index n) f r => P n -> (Return (Index n) f r -> r) -> f -> Replace (Index n) f r
compose x = compose' (convert x)
  where
    convert :: P n -> P (Index n)
    convert P = P

-- This does not type check without a signature due to the monomorphism restriction.
compBinRel :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> (a -> a -> Bool)
compBinRel = compose (P::P 2) not

-- This is an example where we compose over higher order functions.
-- Think of it as composing (a -> (b -> c)) and ((b -> c) -> c).
-- This will not typecheck without signatures, despite the fact that it has arguments.
-- However, it will if we use the first solution.
appSnd :: b -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> c
appSnd x f = compose (P::P 1) ($ x) f
```

However, this implementation has a few downsides, as annotated in the source.

I attempted (and failed) to use closed type families to infer the composition index automatically. It *might* have been possible to infer higher order functions like this:

```
-- Given r and f, where f = x1 -> x2 -> ... -> xN -> r, Infer r f returns N.
type family Infer r f where
    Infer r r = Zero
    Infer r (a -> f) = Succ (Infer r f)
```

However, `Infer` won't work for higher order functions with polymorphic arguments. For example:

```
ghci> :kind! forall a b. Infer a (b -> a)
forall a b. Infer a (b -> a) :: *
= forall a b. Infer a (b -> a)
```

GHC can't expand `Infer a (b -> a)` because it doesn't perform an occurs check when matching closed family instances. GHC won't match the second case of `Infer` on the off chance that `a` and `b` are instantiated such that `a` unifies with `b -> a`.

Comment: The GHC 7.8 version is pretty good. Can you replace `(prev n)` with `(P::P (n-1))` in the second instance if you use `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}`?

Comment: @ntc2 Absolutely. The reason I wrote `prev` is because I was just too lazy to scroll to the top of the file and add the pragma :)

Comment: OK, so I guess that makes the 7.8 version as a good as I could hope for.  One more thing: assuming `(0-1) ~ 0`, it seems those 7.8 instances overlap. So, did you use `{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}`?

Comment: The update is interesting! I wrote some code like that in 7.6.3 recently -- for calculating the arguments and return type of a function, and for substituting the return type -- but that only works for function types that end with a monad.  Because there are no closed type families in 7.6.3, with ordered instances, it didn't seem possible to identify the base case (your overlapping `Arity` instances work because they are ordered?).  But then I realized something: the the base case is not necessarily well defined: you might want to compose with a higher order function! So,still want  `compose'`.

Comment: Yes, `Arity` works because of overlapping instances are ordered. And `Inst` was a typo :)

Comment: There is a lot of good stuff in your answer, but I'm accepting specifically for the template Haskell trick: it effectively adds type-level literals to the injective-successor version in 7.6.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately your question cannot be answered in principle in the currently released version of GHC (GHC 7.6.3) because of a consistency problem pointed out in the recent message
http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2013-December/111942.html

Although type-level numerals look like numbers they are not guaranteed to behave like numbers at all (and they don't). I have seen Iavor Diatchki and colleagues have implemented proper type level arithmetic in GHC (which as as sound as the SMT solver used as a back end -- that is, we can trust it). Until that version is released, it is best to avoid type level numeric literals, however cute they may seem.

Comment: I see the inconsistency in the email you link to ("singletons" are not singletons), but I don't understand how it relates directly to my question.