# Changing the return type of a function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Is there is a succinct way to change the return type of a function?

Consider **for example** `comparing` in `Data.Ord`. It returns an `Ordering`. Yet I am only interested in whether the two items are equal or not. So I need to convert the resulting `Ordering` to a `Bool`.

A straight forward way I can think of is:

```
isEqualOn f x y = if comparing f x y==EQ then True else False
```

(or `isEqualOn f x y = comparing f x y==EQ` as here as pointed out in the comments).

Is there a more compositional way to do this (sort of adapting `comparing` or writing it in a pointless manner) without having to write out everything? Ideally, I am looking for something that works on n-ary functions as well.

-- Update --

As suggested by the answers/comments, the specific example above (`isEqualOn`) can be implemented using the standard `on` function as `on (==)`. However, my question is about the general technique to change function return types in a compositional/pointless manner as exemplified by the SEC approach in the comments.

Comment: @luqui sure , this is shorter.

Comment: Oh I deleted it.  For future reference, it was `isEqualOn f x y = comparing f x y == EQ`.

Comment: And in general you have the function `(== EQ) :: Ordering -> Bool`, and having a function which gets you from where you are to where you want to be is basically the most compositional thing you can have (though you might find it notationally inconvenient until you get more comfortable with working with composition)

Comment: `isEqualOn = (result.result.result) (== EQ)` using the [SEC](http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators) approach.  See that link or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413930/how-to-compose-not-with-a-function-of-arbitrary-arity/415154) for more.

Comment: @luqui The SEC approach seems to be the right answer. If you write an answer about it in this case, I'll accept it.

Comment: _my question is about the general technique to change function return types_ pay attention: you are asking for function composition. You don't like `a -> b` because you want `c`? write your `b -> c` function and compose those two to get `a -> c`. That's exactly what your answer suggests. There's not much more to it.

Comment: @AndrasGyomrey Note, that the type of the function to be changed is *not* `a -> b` (i.e. not unary), but `a -> b (->...) -> c`. It is to be changed to `a -> b (-> ...) -> d`. The only thing I've seen doing it is the SEC approach linked in the comments. It takes some digestion though.

Answer (score 5):

Your definition of `isEqualOn` would be the same as `on (==)`:

```
\> import Data.Function (on)
\> :t (on (==))
(on (==)) :: Eq a1 => (a -> a1) -> a -> a -> Bool
```

for example to compare on absolute value:

```
\> let isEqualOn = on (==)
\> isEqualOn abs 2 (-2)
True
```

Comment: `on` is more commonly written as an infix: ``((==)`on`abs) 2 (-2)``. Or, of course more relevant is an example like ``groupBy ((==)`on`abs) [1,2,-2,-3,3,4]``, which gives `[[1],[2,-2],[-3,3],[4]]`.

Comment: Thanks. But I am interested in the general approach to convert functions. For example, I may need to derive a `less` predicate out of `comparing` by changing the return type. :)  (That's why I used bold font on "for example")

Comment: I think of "on" as a preposition, so I always use `on` infix; I'd write ``(==) `on` f`` instead of `on (==) f`.

Comment: Ha, @leftaroundabout beat me to the punch again.

Comment: @tinlyx Besides the compositional approaches that actually call `comparing` given in the comments to your question, you should seriously consider this answer for your actual code. It is easy to adapt to a `less` predicate: just use `on (<)` instead.

Comment: @tinlyx luqui's comments do answer the real question, in my opinion.

Comment: @tinlyx And luqui's comments show how to adapt a function by the return type to get a new function.

Comment: @tinlyx, in practice, it tends to pay to design library APIs and the basic functions you build your code on as well as you possibly can. That way, you end up spending as little time and code as possible making round pegs fit in square holes. `on` is a much better building block than ``comparing = (compare `on`)``.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you can use the function `on` from Data.Function, but
perhaps you are looking for the operator `==` which returns a `Bool`.
In which case your function can be written as:

```
isEqualOn f x y = fx == fy
```

and personally I would never write this particular function but
"inline" it where it is used.

On the more general matter of "changing the return type". What you are looking for is composition:

```
isEq Eq = True
isEq _  = False

equal x y = isEq (comparing x y)
```

or more haskell flavored:

```
equal x = isEq . comparing x
```