# SQL "Group By" and Having in Haskell?

Tags: sql, haskell, aggregate-functions

I am trying to understand the semantics of SQL `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses by mimicking it in Haskell with a minimal mock-up.

For example, the following SQL taken from the [Postgres tutorial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/tutorial-agg.html)

```
SELECT city, max(temp_lo)
    FROM weather
    GROUP BY city
    HAVING max(temp_lo) < 40;
```

return the cities that have all lowest temperature values below 40.

My understanding is that `HAVING` depends on `GROUP BY`, so `HAVING` can be implemented on top of `GROUP BY`. To keep things simple, I use ordinal numbers to represent columns/fields. So here is what I have:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Function

at = flip (!!)

groupBySql n  = groupBy ((==) `on` (at n)). sortBy (comparing (at n) )

havingGroupBy f n tab = [ filter f | g <- groupBySql 2 tab ]
```

And the test data:

```
--mimick weather table: temp_lo, temp_hi, city
weather = [ [10, 30, 1], 
            [45, 99, 2],
            [0, 3, 3],
            [10, 35, 1],
            [55, 103, 2],
            [5, 29, 3]
          ]

test1 = havingGroupBy ( (<40).(at 0) ) 2 weather
```

But I have an error in writing `havingGroupBy`, and run out of time/energy.

```
*Main> test1

<interactive>:53:1:
    No instance for (Show ([[b0]] -> [[b0]]))
      (maybe you haven't applied enough arguments to a function?)
```

A bunch of questions here:

1. Obviously, I didn't get the types right while mimicking the `HAVING`, how to fix it.
2. Is there a way to add type notation just for a parameter like `f` in `havingGroupBy f n tab = [ filter f | g <- groupBySql 2 tab ]`, for debugging? My intended type for `f` is a boolean function on a row: `[a]->Bool`.
3. Is my understanding of `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` correct so far?

Comment: I don't know. You lost me at `!!` which has no business being in this code. Also, I suggest you write drafts of "having" and "group by" first, then think about what you might need to do to combine them.

Comment: @dfeuer `at = (!!)` is to extract the nth column/field. This is used in `groupBySql` to group rows based upon equality of the "city" field, (i.e. column `2`). I've just asked another question about the equality by a field:  `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34778469/changing-the-return-type-of-a-function-in-haskell

Comment: @dfeuer Regarding your second point, my current understanding is that `HAVING` cannot be written independent from `GROUP BY`. This, of course, is part of my question, both about SQL and the Haskell interpretation.

Comment: Even if I don't particularly enjoy them, note that GHC has [SQL-like list comprehensions](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#generalised-list-comprehensions) as an extension.

Comment: @chi Thanks for pointing that out:) I sometimes think that the description of SQL is based on rules and not very clear. That's why I want to use the clarity of Haskell here.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the `!!`. I wouldn't recommend representing a row by a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Note: This post is written in literate Haskell. You can save it as Main.lhs and try it in your GHCi.</sup>

To model this in Haskell, we should use the appropriate types:

```
> import Data.Function (on)
> import Data.List (maximumBy, sortBy, groupBy)
> import Data.Ord (comparing)
>
> type WEntry = (Int, Int, String)

> temp_lo (t, _, _) = t
> city    (_, _, c) = c
```

Now, a select in SQL can be thought as a function from one (or many) table(s) to a table of results:

```
> type Result = (Int, String)

> select :: [WEntry] -> [Result]
> select = map (\(l,h,c) -> (l, c))
```

Note that this does not account aggregation. Now, we group the entries by their cities:

```
> groupByCity :: [WEntry] -> [[WEntry]]
> groupByCity  = groupBy ((==) `on` city) . sortBy (comparing city)
```

Since both `HAVING` and the original `SELECT` use `max(temp_lo)`, we aggregate the maximum lowest temperature here for some optimization:

```
> aggregate :: [[WEntry]] -> [WEntry]
> aggregate = map (maximumBy (comparing temp_lo))
```

You can think of `groupByCity` and `GROUP BY` as creating temporary sub tables. If we wouldn't use aggregates those tables would be concatenated in the end.

Now we need to filter those with a valid temperature:

```
> having :: [WEntry] -> [WEntry]
> having     = filter ((<40) . temp_lo)
```

And then put all things together:

```
> query :: [WEntry] -> [Result]
> query = select . having . aggregate . groupByCity
```

An alternative would have been

```
havingCity :: [[WEntry]] -> [[WEntry]]
havingCity = filter (not . any ((40<=) . temp_lo))
query = select . aggregate . havingCity . groupByCity
```

The important part is that an aggregate usually folds intermediate results. If you don't use grouping, `max(temp_lo)` will return a single value (the maximum lowest temperature of the whole table). If you group, `max(temp_lo)` will be maximum lowest temperature of a specific group. Likewise `HAVING` makes it possible to check the result an aggregate would return.

Last but not least, here's a main so that you can actually try it:

```
> weather :: [WEntry]
> weather =
>   [ (10,  30, "Berlin")
>   , (45,  99, "San Francisco")
>   , ( 0,   3, "Springfield")
>   , (14,  35, "Berlin")
>   , (55, 103, "San Francisco")
>   , ( 5,  29, "Springfield")
>   ]
>
> main = print $ query weather
> -- Result: [(14,"Berlin"),(5,"Springfield")]
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. It seems to me that the first implementation is more intuitive. The second implementation with `havingCity` seems to have **repeated** the aggregate function `max(temp_lo)` intelligently/unnaturally in the having clause via `not . any ( (40<=) . temp_lo)`. Do you think actual SQL execution will behave like this? i.e. will it be smart enough to implement the same `max()` twice differently?

Comment: @tinlyx Given that both `max(...)` happen on the same `SELECT` level _and_ the same field, I hope that this is the case. That depends on the implementation in your DBMS, but given the example is from the documentation (and the fact that it's basically a `split->map->reduce`), there's strong evidence that for a single-level `SELECT`, PostgreSQL does this kind of optimization. The second variant models a version that's not doing this kind of optimization.